# Failed to find the Facebook client libraries

Tags: social-network

While trying to configure Drupal for Facebook, I followed the readme and copied their code into my settings.php and placed the facebook-php-sdk file into the stated location under sites/all/libraries but I still get this error:

> Failed to find the Facebook client libraries at sites/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php. Read the README.txt and follow the instructions carefully.

I went to publichtml\sites\all\libraries\facebook-php-sdk-master\src and www\sites\all\libraries\facebook-php-sdk-master\src to check if facebook.php exists to be sure and it's there.

Comment: Please run a quick check on the list of steps stated in the README.txt once and If you have done all the steps and still you are getting the error then check for folder/files permissions in libraries/facebook-php-sdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's looking for the file in sites/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php, while your file exists in publichtml/sites/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php and www/sites/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php. The difference is between facebook-php-sdk and facebook-php-sdk-master.

Change the folder name from facebook-php-sdk-master to facebook-php-sdk.

Comment: The newest version of the Facebook PHP SDK (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4) does not contain a facebook.php file in the src folder nor elsewhere in the project. I have been able to get past this step by installing an older version of the Facebook PHP SDK which I found on https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk/tree/v2.1.2.