# facebook modules: Facebook client API not found at sites/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php

Tags: 7, social-network

I installed `facebook autopost`, `drupal for facebook` and other facebook modules. But I am received this error in all of these modules

> Failed to find the Facebook client libraries at sites/all/libraries/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php

This is already asked in [Failed to find the Facebook client libraries](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100990/failed-to-find-the-facebook-client-libraries) but it doesn't answer my question. This is screenshot of the CPanel

[image]

The `src` directory is selected. As you see `Facebook.php` is in there, but it still reports the error. I tried to rename the `Facebook.php` to `facebook.php` Then PHP reports the error

> Fatal error: Class 'Facebook' not found in /home/***/public_html/sites/all/modules/fb/fb.module on line 477

What is the problem?

Comment: Compare the permissions and users of that fodler and its files with another library and report back.

Comment: @NiallMurphy it is the only library in my site. But the files in the `src` have `0644` and the folders `0755` permission.

Comment: Change both to 0777 temporarily and see if the error goes away? It could still be the wrong user. If not, then it's something with the library.

Comment: drush en -y fb_autopost fb_autopost_entity fb_autopost_types && drush download-facebook-php-sdk

Comment: I got a validation error or something on first install but that drush command from the project page and a cache reset made it work. I don't think you have drush but the libraries files are from 14th Jan 2015.

Comment: @NiallMurphy the error was not because of the permissions. I was copying `facebook-php-sdk-v4.0`, But I removed that and copied `facebook-php-sdk-v3.2` files and the error gone away!. Thanks anyway :)